# Inner workings of map() in a specific parsing situation

Tags: python-3.x, string, parsing, integer

I know there are already at least two topics that explain how `map()` works but I can't seem to understand its workings in a specific case I encountered.

I was working on the following Python exercise:

> Write a program that computes the net amount of a bank account based a
> transaction log from console input. The transaction log format is
> shown as following:

```
D 100
W 200
```

> D means deposit while W means withdrawal. Suppose the following input
> is supplied to the program:

```
D 300
D 300
W 200
D 100
```

> Then, the output should be:

```
500
```

One of the answers offered for this exercise was the following:

```
total = 0
while True:
    s = input().split()
    if not s:
        break
    cm,num = map(str,s)

    if cm=='D':
        total+=int(num)
    if cm=='W':
        total-=int(num)

print(total)
```

Now, I understand that map applies a function (str) to an iterable (s), but what I'm failing to see is how the program identifies what is a number in the `s` string. I assume `str` converts each letter/number/etc in a string type, but then how does `int(num)` know what to pick as a whole number? In other words, how come this code doesn't produce some kind of TypeError or ValueError, because the way I see it, it would try and make an integer of (for example) "D 100"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first

```
cm,num = map(str,s)
```

could be simplified as

```
cm,num = s
```

since `s` is already a list of strings made of 2 elements (if the input is correct). No need to convert strings that are already strings. `s` is just unpacked into 2 variables.

> the way I see it, it would try and make an integer of (for example) "D 100"?

no it cannot, since `num` is the second parameter of the string.

if input is `"D 100"`, then `s` is `['D','100']`, then `cm` is `'D'` and `num` is `'100'`

Then since `num` represents an integer `int(num)` is going to convert `num` to its integer value.

The above code is completely devoid of error checking (number of parameters, parameters "type") but with the correct parameters it works.

and `map` is completely useless in that particular example too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the `.split()`, statement before in the `s = input().split()`. This creates a `list` of the values `D` and `100` (or `['D', '100']`), because the default split character is a space ( ). Then the `map` function applies the `str` operation to both `'D'` and `'100'`.

Now the `map`, function is not really required because both values upon input are automatically of the type `str` (strings).

The second question is how `int(num)` knows how to convert a string. This has to do with the second (implicit) argument `base`. Similar to how `.split()` has a default argument of the character to split on, so does num have a default argument to convert to.

The full code is similar to `int(num, base=10)`. So as long as `num` has the values `0-9` and at most 1 `.`, `int` can convert it properly to the base 10. For more examples check out [built in int](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/int).